# Подсчитать среднее количество признака по дням недели

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм с тремя признаками: Месяц, День недели, Номер счета.
Требуется расчет среднего количества заказов по дням недели.
Я смог это сделать за несколько шагов так:

```py
df46s = data.groupby(['Month','Weekday'])['InvoiceNo'].nunique()
```

агрегирую по количеству уникальных записей, потому что в счете могут быть несколько номенклатур товара(признак был в изначальном наборе данных), соответственно такие записи могут повторяться. Далее вывожу индекс в столбец и уже агрегирую по среднему значению:

```py
df46s2 = df46s.reset_index(level = ['Weekday'])
res46 = df46s2.groupby('Weekday')['InvoiceNo'].mean()
```

Вроде все получилось. Но вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать эту задачу более лаконичным способом?

срез данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'InvoiceNo':[536366,536367,536367,566041,571080,540523,540523,540524],
                'StockCode':[22632,84879,84969,22949,23321,20676,22383,22111],
                'CustomerID':[17850,13047,13047,13814,13719,13069,13069,16735],
                'Weekday':['Wednesday','Wednesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Thursday','Sunday','Sunday','Sunday'],
                'Month':[12,12,12,9,10,1,1,1]
               })
```

Comment: 1. Разместите, пожалуйста, образцы данных - до обработки и ожидаемый результат. 2. `Номер счета` уникален в пределах какого периода?

Comment: Номер счета уникален в пределах одного заказа, но в данных он повторяется из-за того, что в заказе несколько позиций. Привел срез данных для понимания

Comment: Посмотрел данные, возник вопрос вообще о возможности корректного вычисления среднего из этих данных. Если взять, например, воскресенье. По вашему расчету получается среднее = 2. Но это если это воскресенье - один и тот же день. А в месяце может быть до 5 воскресений. Если заказы были в два разных воскресенья, то среднее будет не 2, а 1. И то, если не считать остальные воскресенья месяца. На мой взгляд, правильно было бы посчитать кол-во уникальных заказов во все воскресенья и поделить на количество всех воскресений в периоде. На мой взгляд, здесь нужны даты заказов, которых в датасете нет.

Comment: @АлексейР Вы абсолютно правы! Нужно группировать еще и по неделям. Но логика кода от этого не изменится. Вопрос был в другом - есть ли более лаконичный способ кодирования?

Comment: 1. Какой смысл оптимизировать неправильную обработку? 2. Если применять именно такой способ обработки, как вы привели, то пока вижу только возможность избавиться от промежуточных переменных и сделать все в одну строку - что-то вроде `data.groupby('Weekday',as_index=False)['InvoiceNo'].nunique().groupby('Weekday')['InvoiceNo'].mean()`

Comment: Да, я примерно про такое и хотел узнать. Спасибо!